# Nativescript with Angular 2 on Android, how to close my app?

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript

I would like a button. When you tap the button, the application closes, and go to home screen. Not needed to really close the app, just go to home screen.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS you're not allowed by the operating system to programmatically close the app.

I'm not sure it's a good practice on Android, but it has been asked and answered many times on StackOverflow.