# How to add functionality of Google SIgn-In in Phonegap Hybrid HTML app

Tags: javascript, api, google-oauth, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

How to implement Google Login in Phonegap App & also how to check whether the user is logged in or not as soon as the user opens up the app ? I am already aware of the EddyVerbruggen Plugin but it doesn't tells the status of login, it just logs in the user and also its trysilentLogin method doesn't works (yields error : 4) . Without knowing the login status how can I direct my users to the welcome page of my app.

**HTML :**

```
<body onload="init()">
</body>
```

**config.xml :**

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.2.1">

    </plugin>
```

**login.js  :**

```
function init() 
{    

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

}




    var onDeviceReady = function() 
                            { 



        window.plugins.googleplus.trySilentLogin( 
            {

                'scopes': '',
                'offline': false
            },
            function (obj) {


                alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // do something useful instead of alerting


                        alert(' YES LOGGED IN ::: GOOGLE ');

            },
            function (msg) {

              alert(' GOOGLE LOGIN error: ' + msg); //here comes the error : 4

            }
        );
```

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen : Please help

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen : Hey eddy, when I am using the latest version of your plugin 5.2.3,  PGap says build error ? Please help