# Nativescript angular navigate to previous component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a ns-angular app that is structured as follows :

in the `app.component` I have a master `page-router-outlet` with 2 pages

- Login
- Main

Routing is configured in the following way :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'start', loadChildren: './views/login/start.module#StartModule' },
    { path: 'main', loadChildren: './views/main/main.module#MainModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In the main component I have static action bar and a child `router-outlet` that navigates between these components.
Again routing is defined as :

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'main/explore', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'camera', loadChildren: './camera/camera.module#CameraModule' },
            { path: 'explore', loadChildren: './explore/explore.module#ExploreModule' }
        ]
    }
];

export const MainRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(mainRoutes);
```

What currently happens is that if I am in the - let's say- `explore` component ( `/main/explore` ), I navigate to the the camera component ( `/main/camera` ) and I press back on my android device, instead of going back to the explore component I go to the start module.
I read the documentation on angular navigation, but even with the following code

```
android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
    this.routerExtensions.back();
});
```

I am unable to return to the previous component.
How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to overwrite the default Android behavior for the back pressed event [as shown in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41278886/4936697)

Notice the `data.cancel` is set to `true`

```
application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {

    data.cancel = true; // prevents default back button behavior

});
```

Comment: That's awesome dude!! Thank you so much, the navigation happens correctly indeed. I am experiencing another small issue, it seems that when I navigate back the component isn't rendered correctly until I tough an image, textfield etc. Here is a link that shows what happens. What do you think I could do? https://gfycat.com/DangerousIdenticalArabianhorse

Comment: Hard to say - woulkd need the code base to investigate