# Handling 'back' button in nativescript angular2 inside component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to handle 'back' button as shown in [Nativescript handling back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603588/nativescript-handling-back-button-event). There are two methods proposed, and both run ok. My problem is how to interact with my component's local data, since 'android.on' is a global event.

What I want to do is to refresh the display (just by updating the model of a list referenced in an ngFor) when my components receives control again from another display (which the users closes by tapping 'back' button).

I've been trying to access 'activityBackPressedEvent' properties, but I can't find a way to access component data ('shopList').

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";
import { TokenModel } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete";
import { RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete/angular";
import { Utils } from '../../utils';
import * as SocialShare from "nativescript-social-share";
import { android, AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData } from "application";
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";
import {topmost} from "ui/frame";

@Component({
    //selector: "Shopping",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./shopping.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./shopping.component.css']
})

export class ShoppingComponent implements OnInit {
    shopList: string[] = [];
    constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router, private routerExt: RouterExtensions) {
        this.shopList = [];
        this.shopList.push ('sugar');
        this.shopList.push ('milk');
    }

    reload(args: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData): void {
        console.log ('back pressed');
        console.log (this.shopList);  // <<--- "undefined"
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.reload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the application event `activityBackPressedEvent` is a native event and not an Angular one. So in that case to preserve the meaning of `this` you need the good old **this-that** JavaScript pattern.

Here is how to modify your code to work as expected:

```
reload(args: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData): void {
    console.log ('back pressed');
    console.log (this.shopList);  // <<--- "[milk, sugar]"
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let that = this;

    android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (args: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
        that.reload(args);
    });
}
```

Comment: Simple & perfect solution!!!! Thank you very match. I didn't know the that/this pattern.